# Input field filters not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, html

I have successfully implemented *almost* all types of filters in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/oma6peb2/):

```html
<div data-ng-app='' data-ng-init="vehicles=[
                   {type:'car',color:'red'},
                   {type:'bike',color:'black'}]">
  <h1>
        AngularJS <a href='http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp'>
        Filters Example</a>
    </h1>

  <p>Enter text
    <input type='text' data-ng-model='abc' />
  </p>
  <p>The text you entered is
    <br/> <a href='http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_uppercase'>Upper case</a> {{ abc | uppercase }}
    <br/><a href='http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_lowercase'>Lower case</a> {{ abc | lowercase }}</p>Enter amount
  <input type='number' data-ng-model='num1' />
  <p>The <a href='http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_currency'>amount</a> you entered is
    <br/>{{ num1 | currency }}</p> <a href='http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_orderby'> Directives Filter example</a>

  <br/>Vehicles filtered by type:
  <ul data-ng-repeat="v in vehicles | orderBy:'type'">
    <li>{{"Vehicle type is "+v.type +" with color "+ v.color}}</li>
  </ul>
  <br/>Vehicles <a href='http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_input'>filtered by user input:</a>

  <br/>
  <input type="text" ng-model='test' />
  <ul data-ng-repeat="v in vehicles | filter: 'test' | orderBy:'type'">
    <li>{{"Vehicle type is "+v.type +" with color "+ v.color}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Everything is working except [input filters](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_input).

This is how I'm [seeing](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/oma6peb2/embedded/result/) it now:

[image: no output]

> Why is the array not printed and filtered by user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from `'test'` passed to the filter. Since it is not a string, its a model and it should be passed directly to the filter.

```
<ul data-ng-repeat="v in vehicles | filter: test | orderBy:'type'">
    <li>{{"Vehicle type is "+v.type +" with color "+ v.color}}</li>
</ul>
```

The above code will work.

Comment: Thanks @VVK - So it clarified me that input filters doesn't require quotations. Something else one need to avoid in such cases please?